# Motorola DS6878 Barcode scanner

Tags: barcode-scanner, barcode

I have a Motorola DS6878 scanner that I'm trying to get to read a tab. The scanner will scan the tab but doesn't do anything on the computers. Can't give specific details about the scanner as I'm not very proficient with it and I know it reads a multitude of formats from Code128 Code39 and 2D as well.

I want to be able to scan a barcode with a number, scan a barcode to make it go to the next line (tab) and then go on scanning stuff.

I have several zebra 110XiIII 24mm head printers that I can use to print labels.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Side note: We have several wasp scanners that read the barcode just fine, it's only the Motorola ones that won't output the tab function.

Answer (score 0):

With the Motorolas we use, we have to set up the tab or enter on the scanner with specific control barcodes. Once set up, the scanner itself inserts a tab or enter at the end of all scanned barcodes so the barcode doesn't have to contain them.
The control barcodes are on the blue piece of paper comes with the scanners in the box. If you don't have it, the are downloadable from the scanner's support site.